# Elegant regex multimatching in limited space on a single line

Tags: regex, lua, pcre, prompt

I play a mud using mudlet and wish to use Perl regex to capture some input from my prompt. The thing is it seems really hard to do without being overly repetitive in my search. I'm hoping to come up with an elegant solution to

Here is my sample prompt line: `[NESWDNeSeSwNw] [The Palace Square-Bastion] [|Excl] >)|61|(<`

What I want to capture is the list of directions where each direction begins with an uppercase letter and may or may not contain a lower case letter (in case of diagonals only). Valid upper letters are N E S W U D (cardinal indicators) and the valid lowercase letters are e w only (diagonal indicators)

I was trying to use something to the effect of: `^.([NESWUD]{1}[ew]?)+.` (dots to match the brackets since brackets seem to be incapable of being escaped in the pcre that mudlet uses for triggers)

The problem with this solution is that it does not capture all the directions and the greedy matching matches the last directon "`Nw`" only. If I break it down to remove the capture group and the greediness to just `[NESWUD]{1}[ew]?` it gives me the every occurance of the capital letters everywhere not just in my prompt.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why exactly is this tagged with `lua` though? Is a lua-based solution acceptable too?

Comment: You can use \ to excape brackets in Mudlet. Mudlet uses PCRE ([manual](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt)) for the regex matching.

A Lua-based solution is acceptable as well, as Mudlets triggers allow Lua code to be run to match - so anything that returns ``true`` would be considered a match.

Answer (score 0):

```
([NUESWUD][ew]?)(?=[NSEWUDew\]])
```

This will capture `NESWDNeSeSwNw` from `[NESWDNeSeSwNw] [The Palace Square-Bastion] [|Excl] >)|61|(<`

The end look ahead `(?=[NSEWUDew\]])` makes sure its behind only the specified characters meaning it that this wont capture the `S` in `Square` or the `E` in `Excl`.

Try testing this here http://gskinner.com/RegExr/.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that a direction like `We` or `Dw` doesn't make sense and that `e` and `w` can only come after `N` or `S`. What you want is something like `^\[((?:[EWUD]|[NS][ew]?)+)\]`. That will capture all the directions in `$1`, not just the last one.

To explain it I'l use a simpler regex: `((?:[a-z])+)`. `([a-z])+` will match any string of lower case Latin letters but each capture will overwrite the previous one, keeping only the last letter (e.g. `Hello` will return `o`). `((?:[a-z])+)` will match and capture the same string (e.g. `Hello` will return `ello` in $1). `(?:[a-z])` prevents the match from being captured, the `+` increases the match to as many as possible and the outer `(` and `)` then capture that string into `$1`.

You didn't need the `{1}` in your regex as that is always implied.